# how can I visulize the published map?

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used the code https://answers.ros.org/question/286221/create-2d-occupancy-grid-map-by-laser-data/ for map creation in gazebo turtlebot3, but i don't know how visualize the published map.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399015/how-can-i-visulize-the-published-map?/) by [peyman1372](https://answers.ros.org/users/101495/peyman1372/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use this map as a `OccupancyGrid.msg` and use e.g. [rosshow](https://github.com/dheera/rosshow) to visualize ROS topics in a terminal.

Other option is mentioned there:

https://answers.ros.org/question/229596/convert-image-to-occupancy-grid/

(the `map_server` package)

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1